# Ubuntu does not detect hard disk, comreset failed errno16

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

So, my friend sent me a "broken" hard drive, says his dad held the power button during Norton Power Eraser. His dad's PC is fixed now, but I'm stuck with an undetected hard disk. It spins up and ticks like a normal disk, but it is not detected in Ubuntu or the BIOS of my PC. I have also tried this on a Mac, running OS X. Nothing. When I boot Ubuntu with the undetected drive in, it says: `ata1: comreset failed errno16`

Help would be greatly appreciated as I don't want to lose 320 GB :)

Comment: Sounds like total hardware failure. Not much you can do if the drive is not recognized by the bios

Comment: Well, that sucks. I'm going to build a desktop soon so I'll keep it around so see if that will detect it :/